# Find intersection of two columns of a data frame and put the intersection values in new column with comma separated in R

Tags: r

I have data frame with some columns, I am giving example data frame and expected result

```
df:   
name    num1               num2
dkfk    234,445            445,234,651
skrf    1748,7876,432      1748,7876,432,4452,2565
RRK    748,4637           748,4637
DKMs    8474,2426,181      8474,2426,181,748,3733,7652

expected output:
    name    num1               num2                              common
    dkfk    234,445            445,234,651                       651
    skrf    1748,7876,432      1748,7876,432,4452,2565           4452,2565
    RRK     748,4637           748,4637                          NA or empty
    DKMs    8474,2426,181      8474,748,2426,181,3733,7652       748,3733,7652
```

I need solution using dplyr or base R

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setdiff` in `Map` after you have used `strsplit`.

```
sapply(Map(setdiff, strsplit(df$num2, ",", fixed=TRUE),
 strsplit(df$num1, ",", fixed=TRUE)), paste, collapse = ",")
#[1] "651"           "4452,2565"     ""              "748,3733,7652"
```

Comment: A very straightforward and clear method, upvoted!

Comment: I want the output as a data frame

Comment: @Hmm add `df$common <-` in front.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I have edited your answer to match number boundaries. If it works now, maybe you can undelete it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try `gsub` like below

```
f <- function(s1, s2) {
  gsub(
    "^,|,$",
    "",
    gsub(
      ",{2,}",
      ",",
      Reduce(
        function(x, p) gsub(paste0("\\b", p, "\\b"), "", x),
        c(s2, unlist(strsplit(s1, ",")))
      )
    )
  )
}

transform(
  df,
  common = Vectorize(f)(num1, num2)
)
```

or (Thank @GKi's contribution)

```
transform(
  df,
  common = unname(
    Vectorize(gsub)(
#      gsub(",", ",?|", paste0(num1, ",")),
      paste0("(?<!\\d)", gsub(",", "(?!\\\\d),?|(?<!\\\\d)", num1), "(?!\\d),?"),
      "",
      num2,
      perl = TRUE )
  )
)
```

which gives you

```
  name          num1                        num2        common
1 dkfk       234,445                 445,234,651           651
2 skrf 1748,7876,432     1748,7876,432,4452,2565     4452,2565
3  RRK      748,4637                    748,4637
4 DKMs 8474,2426,181 8474,2426,181,748,3733,7652 748,3733,7652
```

Comment: Try it with: `df <- data.frame(name = "x", num1 = "1", num2 = "12")`

Comment: @GKi Yes, that's one case the method here isn't applicable. I just presumed OP has all numbers separated by `,`, and I played some tricks based on this assumption. Yes, your method works in general :)

Comment: Then try this `df <- data.frame(name = "x", num1 = "1,3", num2 = "12,4")` where all numbers separated by `,`.